# Angular 2 HTTP property retryWhen doesn't exist on type Observable<any>

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to retry my requests so that I can get a refresh token before sending the user to log in again however I am getting an error when I try to use `retryWhen` on the request and I'm not sure why.

**http.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ) { }

  public get(url: string, headers?: Headers): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url, this.getHeaders(headers))
      .map(this.extractData)
      .retryWhen((error: any) => { ... }) // [ts] Property 'retryWhen' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using it for a couple days the original solution posted by Omri caused some issues where the property couldn't be found occasionally. (It worked in some builds and not others). I ended up finding a better solution that works more consistently and doesn't require an additional import.

Instead of importing Observable from rxjs/Observable import it from rxjs/Rx.

This **DOES NOT** work:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

This **DOES** work:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Comment: Both of them should work (`'rxjs/Rx'`, `'rxjs/Observable'`, and even only **`'rxjs'`**), Observable is exported multiple times in the RxJS library. Your issue really was that you didn't import the operator. The error you presented in the title confirmed that the type Observable was imported, but the operator wasn't available on it.

Answer (score 10):

You must import the operator first before using it(it works the same for other operators)

Put this in your imports at the top of the file:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retryWhen';
```

It adds this operator on-top of the Observable prototype.

Comment: Weird I had a project before where we didn't need to include that.

Comment: On a slightly related note, any idea why the error passed to retryWhen is of type `Subject` instead of `Response`? This is an issue because Subject doesn't include the status and I need to check if the status was a 401.

Comment: I don't want to confuse you, because I'm myself a bit confused about this operator, I haven't used it before. It apparently passes a notifier function as defined [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retryWhen)

Comment: The signature `public retryWhen(notifier: function(errors: Observable): Observable): Observable` is really hard to get your head around.